# How to get specific data from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to get a players "pp_rank" from this websites API. The code I am using to make the request is:

```
baseUrl = 'https://osu.ppy.sh/api/{}?k=api_key'
url = baseUrl.format("get_user") + "&u=" + username
r = requests.get(url)
stats = r.json()
print(stats)
```

This code provides me with:

> [{'user_id': '11367222', 'username': 'lifeline', 'join_date': '2017-12-19 00:18:20', 'count300': '45329017', 'count100': '4326758', 'count50': '422297', 'playcount': '222948', 'ranked_score': '80664364190', 'total_score': '531251267911', 'pp_rank': '2', 'level': '105.043', 'pp_raw': '22645.8', 'accuracy': '98.44232177734375', 'count_rank_ss': '31', 'count_rank_ssh': '130', 'count_rank_s': '505', 'count_rank_sh': '2497', 'count_rank_a': '2321', 'country': 'ID', 'total_seconds_played': '9463354', 'pp_country_rank': '1', 'events': [{'display_html': "<img src='/images/B_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11367222'>lifeline</b> achieved rank #755 on <a href='/b/2777202?m=0'>Faylan - Enrei Black Out [Disappear] (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': '2777202', 'beatmapset_id': '1340611', 'date': '2023-07-06 02:23:41', 'epicfactor': '1'}, {'display_html': "<img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11367222'>lifeline achieved <b>rank #23 on <a href='/b/2829420?m=0'>yuikonnu & ayaponzu* - Super Nuko World [Cat] (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': '2829420', 'beatmapset_id': '1368212', 'date': '2023-07-06 01:16:36', 'epicfactor': '2'}, {'display_html': "<img src='/images/A_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11367222'>lifeline</b> achieved rank #54 on <a href='/b/4114798?m=0'>Ryokuoushoku Shakai - Natsu o Ikiru [Azure] (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': '4114798', 'beatmapset_id': '1981601', 'date': '2023-07-06 01:07:17', 'epicfactor': '1'}, {'display_html': "<img src='/images/SH_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/11367222'>lifeline achieved <b>rank #2</b> on <a href='/b/4103973?m=0'>MAN WITH A MISSION x milet - Kizuna no Kiseki (TV Size) [Kujinn's Purgatory] (osu!)", 'beatmap_id': '4103973', 'beatmapset_id': '1976994', 'date': '2023-07-06 00:56:40', 'epicfactor': '4'}]}]

When looking at this JSON I want the `pp_rank` of the user so I tried using a simple print statement:

```
print(stats[pp_rank])
```

However this just provides an error and does not work, how do I go about solving this?

Comment: step 1: understand the shape of the data you received. It's a list, so you first need to select the element you want from that list e.g. `stats = r.json()[0]`. Then the element is a dictionary. `"pp_rank"` is a key in the dictionary. Note that the key itself is a string. If `stats` is a dictionary then `stats[pp_rank]` would use the value of a _variable_ `pp_rank` as the key to fetch the value of. But you don't have that variable, the key you want is the actual string `"pp_rank"`. So you should use `stats["pp_rank"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the 1st position of the list (as you see is a list of 1 dictionary (so `[0]`). Then use the `""` characters, as you are trying to access a keyword of the dict, and it is not a variable in the python scope

```py
print(stats[0]["pp_rank"])
```